# How do I have combined keys?

Tags: c#

I want this to have combined keys so you could do CTRL + E instead of something like below.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo thekey = new ConsoleKeyInfo();   
if (thekey.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)    
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to also verify Modifiers property -

```
if(thekey.Key == ConsoleKey.Q 
&& (thekey.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) 
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like below, by checking the `Modifiers` property. See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more on this.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();

if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) 
Console.Write("ALT+ {0}",cki.Key.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could push keys into a queue when they're pressed, and then clear the queue on each valid combination. You can also have a separate list of valid combinations stored as a tree of keypresses, allowing you to clear the queue early when no valid combination can come from a sequence.